# How to append titles to elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I iterate throught all "select" elements and append them titles in right order from firstDay to thirdDay? For now it just shows the last one (thirdDay) on all elements. Thanks a lot for any help!

```
var firstDay = "First day";
var secondDay = "Second day";
var thirdDay = "Third day";

var days = [firstDay, secondDay, thirdDay];
var select = $(".dayNumber");

for(var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
    select.attr('title', days[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear, could you add an example of the intended result?

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well?

Comment: Try `select.eq(i).attr('title', days[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$.fn.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of for loop:

```
var firstDay = "First day";
var secondDay = "Second day";
var thirdDay = "Third day";

var days = [firstDay, secondDay, thirdDay];
var select = $(".dayNumber");

select.each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('title', days[index])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong because you're not selecting a specific *select* element, you should do something like

```
for(var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
    $(select[i]).attr('title', days[i]);
}
```